# pixelation artifact when exporting video using Metal

Tags: swift, avfoundation, metal, avassetwriter

I have a very strange bug and only happens in random devices.
I'm using avassetwriter to export a movie and drawing/shader with Metal, but i get some colored pixelated artifacts in the animated mp4 movie.

[image]

video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g6KyL18JqclOW1kVQkif3o3zaqylYaLk/view?usp=sharing

In the image/frame you can see colored artifact pixels, this usually happens when the line moves(animated line)

Any idea?
thankyou

init

```
    init?(outputURL url: URL, size: CGSize) {

    do {
        assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: url, fileType: .mp4)
    } catch let error{
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
    let compressionProperties = NSDictionary(dictionary: [
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey:ClipSettings.bitrate
        ])

    let outputSettings: [String: Any]
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *),AVAssetExportSession.allExportPresets().contains(AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality) {
        outputSettings = [ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.hevc,
                           AVVideoWidthKey : size.width,
                           AVVideoHeightKey : size.height,
                           AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:compressionProperties
        ]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        outputSettings = [ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                           AVVideoWidthKey : size.width,
                           AVVideoHeightKey : size.height,
                           AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:compressionProperties
        ]
    }

    assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
    assetWriterVideoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = false


    let sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [String: Any] = [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String : size.width,
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String : size.height
    ]

    assetWriterPixelBufferInput = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: assetWriterVideoInput,
                                                                       sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributes)


    if assetWriter.canAdd(assetWriterVideoInput){
        assetWriter.add(assetWriterVideoInput)

    }else{
        print("add failed")
    }
```

this is how write a frame from metal texture

```
    func writeFrame(forTexture texture: MTLTexture, time: TimeInterval, podSticker: PodStickerView) {
    if !isRecording {
        return
    }
    let fps: Int32 = 60
    let intervalDuration = CFTimeInterval(1.0 / Double(fps))
    let timescale: Float = 600
    let kTimescale: Int32 = Int32(timescale)
    let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(
        value: Int64( floor(timescale / Float(fps)) ),
        timescale: kTimescale
    )

    var waitTime = 300.0 //fixes dropped frames
    while !assetWriterVideoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        let waitIntervale: TimeInterval = 0.001 * waitTime
        let maxDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: waitIntervale)
        RunLoop.current.run(until: maxDate)
        waitTime += 200.0 // add 200ms every time

    }

    guard let pixelBufferPool = assetWriterPixelBufferInput.pixelBufferPool else {
        print("Pixel buffer asset writer input did not have a pixel buffer pool available; cannot retrieve frame")
        return
    }

    var maybePixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    let status  = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, pixelBufferPool, &maybePixelBuffer)
    if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        print("Could not get pixel buffer from asset writer input; dropping frame...")
        return
    }

    guard let pixelBuffer = maybePixelBuffer else { return }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])
    let pixelBufferBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)!

    // Use the bytes per row value from the pixel buffer since its stride may be rounded up to be 16-byte aligned
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height)

    texture.getBytes(pixelBufferBytes, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)

    let presentationTime = CMTimeMultiply(frameDuration, multiplier:  Int32(frameNumber))
    Engine.renderTime = presentationTime.seconds



        //write video
        self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer,[])
```

//        }
    }

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? How does your processing code look like? How do you combine it with the `AVAssetWriter`?

Comment: edited: note it only happens in some devices, not all but a lot

Comment: Hmm, very strange. I guess there's some kind of timing problem between `texture.getBytes` and `AVAssetWriter` writing the data to the video. Is it always the same kind of device this problem is occurring on? Also, it would probably more efficient to render directly into the pixel buffer (wrapped into a texture) instead of copying the data in each frame.

Comment: yes it happens in the same devices each time, also when I reduced the size of the video from 720x720 to 256x256 artifacts are gone.
 how would i render directly into pixel buffer. im using makeBlitCommandEncoder to draw to a mtltexture

Comment: By the looks of if this could also be compression artifacts of some kind. Have you tried using different video settings?

Comment: i played with AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,bitrate,AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey
  but i dont see any changes

Comment: Could you maybe try a different codec?

Comment: tried hevc and h264... could it be kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey?

Comment: That should be correct. It might also be the metal code that's failing on some devices. Did you inspect (QuickLook in Xcode) the texture before it's written to the video to see if the artifacts are in there already?

Comment: yes i checked the frames from metal texture and they're correct

Comment: I learned if I add a delay in the processing the artifacts go away... could it be that avassetwriter is encoding too fast for metal texture to release/update kinda?

Comment: Where in the processing did you insert the delay? Do you make sure that the Metal processing is finished before you try to `getBytes` from the texture? (For instance by calling `waitUntilCompleted()` on the command buffer or, better, by adding a completion handler that then triggers the writing to the video.)

Comment: I was able to figure it out with texture usage change to .shaderWrite,
and seems to do the trick some type of compression was going on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "In iOS devices with GPU family 5, Metal doesn’t apply lossless compression to a given texture if you set any of these options:"

Comment: Oh nice, good to hear! Consider writing an answer to help others that encounter this issue.

Comment: will do, just need to confirm other devices work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the usage of the MTLTexture from .shaderRead to .shaderWrite.

according to apple "In iOS devices with GPU family 5, Metal doesn’t apply lossless compression to the given texture if you set this option."